# Логическая ошибка коде на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, pyqt5, оптимизация

Изучаю *GUI* по книге "**`PyQt 5 для лингвистов: профессионально ориентированное программирование`**", задание:

1. <del>получить список букв из input</del>,
2. <del>найти все совпадения в базе с заданной длиной</del>,
3. **использовать каждую букву столько раз сколько она была введена**

Пытаюсь оптимизировать код, изначально он просто ужасный:

```
def creepy(self, number, index_in_word, simbol):
    """принимает номер который в конечном итоге передаётся прогресс бару,
    индрекс в слове и символ"""
    if simbol not in self.set_lettrs:
        # если не входит в множесто добавляем 
        self.set_lettrs.add(simbol)
        # присваиваем значение по индексу в списке строк
        self.res[index_in_word] = simbol

    if index_in_word == len(self.res)-1:
        # когда индекс равен длине списка строк: обнуляем словарь 
        self.set_lettrs = set()
        # передаём для прогресса номер
        self.progress_word(number)

def word_search(self):
    # все приготовления(чтение файла, создание списка слов нужной длины и т.д.)
    self.before()
    self.res = ['']*self.word_length  # пустой список нужной длины

    self.set_lettrs = set()  # множество, так как хотел избавиться от повторений

    for number, i in enumerate(self.letters):
        # чем дленнее слово тем больше должно быть циклов for(как их уменьшит не пойму)
        self.creepy(number, 0, i)

        for j in self.letters:
            self.creepy(number, 1, j)

            for k in self.letters:
                self.creepy(number, 2, k)

                for p in self.letters:
                    self.creepy(number, 3, p)
```

Если у меня будет сто символьное слово, не хочется делать 100 циклов `for`, как эту проблему правильно решить?

Думал через `re`, но они просто ищут по шаблону - или я чего-то не понял. 
Хоть я и делаю всё через множество, в надежде что оно удалит повторы. Но повторы есть вывод получается: "ЛАВА, ЛАДА, ЛАПА" хотя букву **`А`** единожды вводил.

Изначально в книге вот такой код:

```
def wordFour(self, letters):
    
    self.cancelled = False
    
    self.t1 = time.time()
    self.c = 0
    self.resArr = []
    self.initW = letters
    self.res = ["", "", "", ""]
    self.r = open("dict.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    self.fileRead = self.r.read()
    self.fileSplit0 = self.fileRead.split()
    self.fileSplit = []
    for word in self.fileSplit0:
        if len(word) == 4:
            self.fileSplit.append(word)
    self.r.close()
    
    self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressDialog("Searching...", "Stop", 0, len(self.initW), self.ui.lineEdit)
    self.progress.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
    self.progress.setMinimumDuration(1000)
    
    for self.i in range(0, len(self.initW)):
        self.res[0] = self.initW[self.i]
        
        self.progress.setValue(self.i)
        if self.progress.wasCanceled():
            self.cancelled = True
            self.ui.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
            return
        
        for self.q in range(0, len(self.initW)):
            if (self.q != self.i):
                self.res[1] = self.initW[self.q]
                
                for self.p in range(0, len(self.initW)):
                    if (self.p != self.i) and (self.p != self.q):
                        self.res[2] = self.initW[self.p]
                        
                        for self.pp in range(0, len(self.initW)):
                            if (self.pp != self.i) and (self.pp != self.q) and (self.pp != self.p):
                                self.res[3] = self.initW[self.pp]
                                
                                self.wordFor = self.res[0] + self.res[1] + self.res[2] + self.res[3]
                                if self.wordFor in self.fileSplit:
                        
                                    if self.wordFor not in self.resArr:
                                        self.resArr.append(self.wordFor)
                                
                                self.c += 1
    self.str = "Найдено совпадений: " + str(len(self.resArr)) + "\n" + self.arrOutput(self.resArr) + "\n" + str(self.c) + " комбинаций проверено\nВремя исполнения: " + str(time.time() - self.t1) + " с." 
    self.ui.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(self.str)
    self.progress.deleteLater()
    
    self.ui.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
```

Я разбил на отдельные функции, но вопрос с `for` остаётся, если я хочу найти слово длинной 10 букв, то мне придётся написать 10 `for`, следовательно, что-то я делаю не правильно.

Comment: Для улучшения вопроса добавьте входные данные и ожидаемый результат. А так, я понимаю, что у вас правильно работает, просто хотите оптимизировать код?

Comment: что-то вы делаете не так. Приведите рабочий пример, который с вашей точки зрения `просто ужасный` и который вы пытаетесь оптимизировать.

Comment: Допустим я ввожу: Запрос: фывапролд
Найдено совпадений: 32
адов, арап, арфа, ввод, вода, двор, драп, дыра, лава, лавр, лада, лады, лапа, лафа, лорд, овал, овод, опал, орда, пава, папа, пара, плов, плод, подо, пола, поло, пора, роды, рыло, фара, фора.
6561 комбинаций проверено
Время исполнения: 0.27773308753967285 с. **Но если длина будет 10символов, то придётся писать 10 for, как этого избежать?**

Comment: Давайте я попробую описать вашу задачу: 1. Есть словарь. 2 Вводим слово. 3. Ищем в словаре слова в которых буквы введенного слова встречаются столько же раз сколько во введенном слове. Правильно?

Comment: Почти всё верно, есть txt фаил, я его открываю, делаю список, удаляю все что не соответствует заданной длине слов которые собираюсь найти, а затем пытаюсь из этих слов найти те слова в которых есть буквы которые мы ввели в инпут, перебрав все комбинации из возможных. Алгоритм в принципе работает, но в примере только для слов длиной в 4символа. А если будет слово длиной 10 символов, то нужно будет дописать ещё 6 циклов for как этого избежать не понимаю. Простите, если не очень хорошо излагаю суть вопроса, просто уже больше недели думаю над алгоритмом, но не понимаю как сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пришлось заглянуть в книгу, которую вы изучаете.
Ваша настороженность оправдана, действительно есть что оптимизировать.

Я считаю, что ваше предложение использовать библиотеку `itertools` - оптимально.

Я бы предложил еще заменить виджеты `QPlainTextEdit` на `QTextEdit`,
чтобы иметь возможность использовать **форматированный текст**
и `QSpinBox` мне кажется лучше подойдет чем `QComboBox`.

Поправил немного **чтение файла**.

Использование `Progressbar` в данном примере, посчитал нецелесообразным,
т.к. если процесс будет тяжелым, то надо будет организовывать потоки
и тогда уже визуализировать `progress-bar`.

Если заполнить файл **dict.txt** каким-нибудь текстом, 
то можно увидеть как все это работает.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from itertools import permutations


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)     # - QPlainTextEdit
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)                             # + True
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)       # - QComboBox
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.label.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.PreventContextMenu)
        self.label.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 413, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Guess Word Demo"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Guess Word"))


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.spinBox.setRange(3, 10)
        self.spinBox.setValue(4)
        self.spinBox.setPrefix(" Букв в слове: ")
        self.spinBox.setWrapping(True)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start1)

        self.statusbar.showMessage('© Alexey Gorozhanov, 2014', 3000)

        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Введите перечень букв, из которых составлено слово. ')

    def start1(self):
        len_word = self.spinBox.value()
        self.word(self.lineEdit.text(), len_word) 

    def word(self, letters, len_word):       
        t1 = time.time()

        # в каком виде (список, множество, словарь) 
        # должны быть `listPermutations` и `fileSplit`, вопрос дискусионный      
        listPermutations = { ''.join(item) for item in permutations(letters, len_word) } 

        # Выбираем слова заданной длины
        # Обратите внимание, что элемент `fileSplit` состоит из `(w.lower(), w)`
        with open('dict.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            fileSplit = [ [w.lower(), w] for w in  f.read().split() if len(w)==len_word ]    

        # сопоставлянм `listPermutations` и `fileSplit`
        self.resArr = [ word_2 for word_1, word_2 in fileSplit if word_1 in listPermutations ]

        _str = """
            Слова должны состоять из букв: <b style='{c}'>{}</b>.<br>
            Слов длиной в <b style='{c}'>{}</b> буквы - <b style='{c}'>{}</b>, выбрано из `dict.txt`.<br>
            Составлено комбинаций с введенных букв(<b style='{c}'>{}</b>) по <b style='{c}'>{}</b> буквы.<br>        
            Найдено совпадений: <b style='{c}'>{}</b><br><br>
            <b>{}</b> <br><br>
            Время исполнения: {} с.<br>
            ======================================<br>
        """.format(
                   letters,
                   len_word, 
                   len(fileSplit), 
                   len(listPermutations), 
                   len_word, 
                   len(self.resArr),
                   self.arrOutput(self.resArr),
                   str(time.time() - t1),
                   c='color:#f00;'
                  )
        self.textEdit.append(_str)

    def arrOutput(self, arr):
        arr.sort()
        return ',  '.join(arr) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    default_font = QtGui.QFont()
    default_font.setPointSize(12)
    app.setFont(default_font)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваше решение изумительно и действительно не нуждается в Progressbar, так как вы не выполняете ненужную работу. Спасибо за ваши комментарии - очень нужно для нас новичков. **Подскажите одно почему вы не использовали f {} строки? они медленнее formata?**

Comment: @DmitrijJakovlev 
Вы не писали какую версию `python-3.x` используете. 
Начиная с версии `3.6` в Python появился новый тип строк — `f-строки`, 
которые буквально означают `formatted string`. 
Эти строки улучшают читаемость кода, а также работают быстрее чем другие способы форматирования. 
`f-строки` - это пятый способ форматирования строк в Python, 
который очень похож на использование метода format().

Answer (score 1):

Ключ к успеху оказалась стандартная библиотека, а именно, модуль `itertools`.   Импортируем из него `permutations`:

```
for item in permutations('ИНТЕРЕСУЮЩАЯ НАС ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТЬ', len)
    print(''.join(item))
```